# How to enable extra buttons on trackball?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, xinput, libinput

On FreeBSD `xev` only recognizes clicks from the first 9 buttons from the Elecom Huge trackball. On Arch Linux clicks from all the 12 buttons are recognized.

As per recommendation from [libinput configuration for ELECOM HUGE](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/blog/linux/libinput-elecom-huge.html) I have added file `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-trackball.conf` with following contents:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "ELECOM trackball catchall"
        MatchProduct "ELECOM TrackBall Mouse HUGE TrackBall"
        #MatchVendor "ELECOM_TrackBall_Mouse"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Buttons" "12"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 2  2 11 12"
        Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "12"
        Option "EmulateWheelTimeout" "0"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
        Option "ScrollButton" "12"
EndSection
```

This is working only partially, as buttons 8 and 9 are remapped to 2, but buttons 10-12 are still not recognised.

How do i enable buttons 10-12?